# Fatal error in onDataChange java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, object, null, tostring

This is my code which should check the order state in the firebase database and display a message for the user.
In this line,

```
 String shippingstate = snapshot.child("state").getValue().toString();
```

I got on a null object reference fatal error and the app was force closed.
I verified all the child values in the database and their match but still get the error.
Can you help me solve it, please?
thanks

```
private void checkorderstate()
{
    DatabaseReference orderref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("orders");
    orderref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists())
            {

                **String shippingstate = snapshot.child("state").getValue().toString();**
                String username = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


                if (shippingstate.equals("shipped"))
                {
                    txttotalamount.setText("Dear "+ username+"\n order is shipped successfully");
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtmsg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtmsg1.setText("Dear "+username+"\n Your order is completed and shipped successfully");
                    nextproccessbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "You can put new order after your current order get shipped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (shippingstate.equals("not shipped"))
                {
                    txttotalamount.setText("Dear "+ username+"Order State: not shipped");
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtmsg1.setText("Dear "+username+"\n your order under proccess, please wait the order shipped massage. thank you");
                    nextproccessbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "You can put new order after your current order get shipped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
```

Debugger Statement:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: net.lazared.myamaze, PID: 3304
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
> at net.lazared.myamaze.CartActivity$3.onDataChange(CartActivity.java:189)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: I suggest you add print or logging statements, or even better use a debugger to step through your code when executed (if possible), to understand exactly what is inside the DataSnapshot that this listener executes on.

Comment: What if `snapshot.child("state")` returns `null` or what if `getValue()` returns `null`?

Comment: both the child and the value for child are not null in database

Comment: how i can add the debugger statement here? im just new in stackoverflow.

Comment: maybe try replacing `snapshot.child("state").getValue().toString()` with `String.valueOf(snapshot.child("state").getValue())`. This would not throw if `getValue` returns null. This is for the sake of experiment solely. In more general case I recommend that you check the value against `null` with an `if` as `valueOf` null returns the ugly string `"null"` which for most cases is not that useful.

Comment: after replacing with String.valueOf(snapshot.child("state").getValue()); its worked without null exception but the if statements been ignored  .

Comment: Your last comment and debugger statement indicate that the result of `snapshot.child("state").getValue()` is in fact `null`. If you can't step-debug, try using `System.out` to print everything in the snapshot, such as by making use of `snapshot.hasChildren()` and iterating (looping) over `snapshot.getChildren()`. It may not be (by all appearances isn't) the object that you're expecting from the database.

Comment: thank you Thomas. i catch the mistake, i was not calling the primary key from the main child in database and that leaded to null value in other objects. thank you again for help.